# How to count HashMap values using a predicate in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying this, but doesn't work:

```
let map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(1, "aaa");
map.insert(2, "bbb");
let a = map.counts_by(|k, v| v.starts_with("a"));
```

What is the right way?

Comment: I dont see any type of "count" functions on a hashmap, so I think you need to convert it to an iterator, filter, then get the count from that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that iterates over collections in Rust is going to factor through the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) API, and unlike in Java where iterators are often implicitly used, it's very common in Rust to *explicitly* ask for an iterator (with `.iter()`) and do some work directly on it in a functional style. In your case, there are three things we need to do here.

1. Get the values of the `HashMap`. This can be done with the [`values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.values) method, which returns an iterator.
2. Keep only the ones satisfying a particular predicate. This is a [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) operation and will produce another iterator. Note that this does not *yet* iterate over the hash map; it merely produces another iterator capable of doing so later.
3. Count the matches, using [`count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count).

Putting it all together, we have

```
map.values().filter(|v| v.starts_with("a")).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should filter an iterator of the `HashMap`, then count the elements of the iterator:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, "aaa");
    map.insert(2, "bbb");

    assert_eq!(
        map.iter().filter(|(_k, v)| v.starts_with("a")).count(),
        1
    );
}
```

Notice that the map also has to be marked as `mut` in order to insert new elements, and the `filter` closure destructures into a tuple containing the key and the value, rather than accepting two separate parameters.